# Headache getting php and sql server 2005 to run together

Tags: php, sql-server

Below is the code that i cannot get to work. I know i have established a connection to the database but this returns nothing. What am i doing wrong?

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE path = ?";
$params = array("blah");
$row = sqlsrv_query($conn, $result, $params);

$finished = sqlsrv_fetch_array($row);


if($finished)
{
echo "blach";
}
```

Comment: If everything exists and is correct, maybe you are testing with a no results query?

Comment: What is the value of $row after your call?

Comment: $row is blank after the query

Answer (score 1):

You may need to replace your ntwdblib.dll as explanied on the [mssql_connect() page of the php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php).

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth checking that the query is not returning an error?

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE path = ?";
$params = array("blah");
$row = sqlsrv_query($conn, $result, $params);

if( $row === false ) {
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

This is the error it produces. Cheers

Comment: odd.. what's the column type form images.path ?

Comment: what happens if you do

$params = array(array('blah', SQLSRV_PARAM_IN,
SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR),
SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR('max')
));

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't use a literal?  Most of the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201(SQL.90).aspx) use variables.

I'd try:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE path = ?";
$var = "blah";
$row = sqlsrv_query($conn, $result, array($var));

$finished = sqlsrv_fetch_array($row);
```